# The iphone distribution Build is not installing on clients iphone but it works for me

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've created an app for client, created a new distribution certificate and provisioning profile for it.

Then I created a new `.ipa` and a wireless link for client. The `.ipa` and link both installs in my device but its not working for my clients iPhone.

Its not because of UDID. I've already checked it so many times.

I've added armv7, armv6 and i386 also.

Can anybody tell me, what would be the reason?

Below are the details of clients device.

> version : 5.1.1(9B206) Available space : 9.6 GB Model : MD234E

Comment: What does that "not working" cover? Crashing? Unexpected/incorrect computation resulst? Or what else?

Comment: I don't know whats wrong in your specific case, and probably no-one will without knowing some more information (error logs etc). I also don't know what a "wireless link" is. The way that I create and deploy to clients is to use a website called www.testflightapp.com. It's a brilliant website where it deals with all the provisioning and deployment. All you have to do is create your `.ipa`, sign it with the provisioning profile you've created and then upload it to testflight. Once there testflight will push the update to your client's device. I've never had any problems doing it this way. Try it

Comment: You need to add your client's device to your provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add client's UDID on provisioning profile, download updated provisioning profile and sign the app with your adhoc distribution setting, convert .app file to .ipa and share it using https://testflightapp.com/, also make sure to check all devices while uploading your build on TestFlight.
I don't know what's your exact error.Let me know if you have any doubt.